# Return all documents in elastic that have a specified property regardless of value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query elastic search using the REST API into returning me all documents that contain a specific property name of "content_blake3". the value of the property is irrelevant, I just want documents that have this property.

ive tried using the must and must_not requests like below but still not getting the result I need

```
GET index-doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must_not": {
          "match":{
            "content_blake3": ""  
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

any help is always appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for the exists query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

```
GET index-doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "filter": {
          "exists":{
            "field": "content_blake3"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```